# check for Valid Parentheses in c++

Tags: c++

Given a string containing just the characters '(', ')', '{', '}', '[' and ']', determine if the input string is valid.

The brackets must close in the correct order, "()" and "()[]{}" are all valid but "(]" and "([)]" are not.

Fails again and again...should return true for input--"()[]{}"---but it return false...

```
class Solution {
public:
    bool isValid(string s) {
        map<char,char>m;
        m['(']=')';
        m['{']='}';
        m['[']='}';int i;string c="";int j;
        for(i=0;i<s.length();i++){
            if((s[i]=='(')||(s[i]=='{')||(s[i]=='[')){
               c=c+(s.at(i));
            }else if((s[i]==')')||(s[i]=='}')||(s[i]==']')){
                j=c.length();
                if(j==0){
                    return false;
                }
                if(m[c[j-1]]!=s[i]){
                    return false;
                }else{
                  c= c.substr(0,j-1);
                }
            }
        }
        if(c.length()){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

Comment: Have you considered to use *recursion* to write this logic?

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: This is interesting story, but you forgot to put actual question. Did you use debugger to pinpoint where problem appears?

Comment: this  m['[']='}' should  be m['[']=']'

Comment: This is a stack problem. You need to push the open parentheses to a stack, and if you encounter a close parenthesis, compare it with the stack's first element if it matches. If it does, pop the element, if it doesn't give error. And at the end, you should check if the stack is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do this using a stack:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Solution {
public:
  bool isValid(std::string s) {
    std::vector<char> stk;
    for (char c : s) {
      switch (c) {
      case '(':
      case '{':
      case '[':
        stk.push_back(c);
        break;
      case ')':
        if (stk.empty() || stk.back() != '(')
          return false;
        stk.pop_back();
        break;
      case '}':
        if (stk.empty() || stk.back() != '{')
          return false;
        stk.pop_back();
        break;
      case ']':
        if (stk.empty() || stk.back() != '[')
          return false;
        stk.pop_back();
        break;
      }
    }
    return stk.empty();
  }
};

int main()
{
  Solution tester;
  std::cout << std::boolalpha << tester.isValid("asdf(as[x]df)") << "\n";
  std::cout << std::boolalpha << tester.isValid("asdf(as[x}df)") << "\n";
}
```

Output

```
true
false
```

Answer (score 0):

While I was doing this problem from LeetCode the issue I faced is when some edge cases were introduced like "]". In these cases, a normal stack approach failed (with my logic) as the top had nothing so I came up with this

```
class Solution
{
public:
  bool isValid(string s)
  {
    stack<char> s1;
    s1.push('I');
    for(int i = 0; i< s.length(); i++)
    {
        if( s[i] == '(' || s[i] == '{' || s[i] == '[' )
            s1.push(s[i]);

        else if
        (
            (s1.top() == '(' && s[i] == ')') ||
            (s1.top() == '{' && s[i] == '}') ||
            (s1.top() == '[' && s[i] == ']')
        )
        s1.pop();
        else 
            s1.push(s[i]);
    }
    if(s1.size() == 1)
        return true;
    return false;
   }
};
```

Answer (score -3):

I think we can apply very simple algorithm for this case unless you have to do something else.

```
bool isValid(string s) {
   bool isvalid = true;
   for(int i = 0; i < s.length() ; i++ ) {

   if((s[i] == '(' && s[i+1] ==')') || 
       (s[i] == '{' && s[i+1] =='}') || 
       (s[i] == '[' && s[i+1] ==']'))
     continue;

    isvalid = false;
    break;
   }
 return isvalid;
}
```

Comment: The word is 'algorithm'. It is derived from somebody's name. Abbreviation not acceptable.

Comment: 1) What will your code print for `([])`? 2) your code has undefined behavior, when `i = s.length () - 1`.

Comment: As per questions, it should return false for ([]), if you look at statement "The brackets must close in the correct order, "()" and "()[]{}" are all valid but "(]" and "([)]" are not."

Comment: @CKT And how does brackets close in the wrong order in `([])`? I read his problem statement. Did you?